# Error "Can not resolve reference to multiname unambiguously"

Tags: facebook, apache-flex, flex3

Personal is giving this error and I can not solve it.

```
Can not resolve reference to multiname unambiguously. FacebookMobile (from C: \ Users \ 
Robinho \ Adobe Flex Builder 4.6 \ FacebookMobile \ src \ FacebookMobile.mxml) and 
com.facebook.graph: FacebookMobile (from C: \ Users \ Robinho \ Adobe Flex Builder 4.6 \ 
FacebookMobile \ libs \ GraphAPI_Mobile_1_8_1 . swc (com.facebook.graph: FacebookMobile)) 
are available.
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two classes with same name `FacebookMobile` one is defined by `FacebookMobile.mxml` and other exists in `GraphAPI_Mobile_1_8_1.swc` (library).

You should avoid naming new classes as ones that already defined by libraries you use. (If they properly namespaced this should not be an issue, but this probably isn't a case)