# Can not resolve a multiname reference unambiguously. flash.text:Font while work with purePdf

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, fonts, purepdf

I am working with purePDF. It looks the Font Class between playerglobal and purePDF is get conflicted.. Can someone please help me out!!!

**Full Error**

Can not resolve a multiname reference unambiguously. flash.text:Font (from C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\sdks\4.6.0\frameworks\libs\player\11.1\playerglobal.swc(flash.text:Font)) and org.purepdf:Font (from D:\proj\Top\libs\purePDF.swc(org.purepdf:Font)) are available. ResultPDF.mxml  /Top/src/com/platina/view/result    Unknown Flex Problem

I have seen a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763936/error-can-not-resolve-reference-to-multiname-unambiguously) related to this error!, but that doesn't help:(

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that whenever you are trying to use `flash.text.Font` you have to write fully qualified class name like above, and whenever you need to use the class from purePDF, you need to write `org.purepdf.Font`. I repeat, everywhere in your code.